# Objective C: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

My app is crashing with the error  "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CALayer firstName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d382c0'".

This is what I was trying to do.

1) I have created a 'Person' class to store information like firstName, lastName, email add and telephone number

Person.m file:

```
@implementation Person
@synthesize firstName, lastName, email, phoneNumber;

-(Person *)initWithfirstName:(NSString *)thisFirstName lastName:(NSString *)thisLastName email (NSString *)thisEmail phoneNumber:(NSString*)thisPhoneNumber
{ 
    if(self = [super init]) 
    {
        self.firstName = thisFirstName;
        self.lastName = thisLastName;
        self.email = thisEmail;
        self.phoneNumber = thisPhoneNumber;
    }
return self;
}
@end
```

2) Store a list of people in a mutable array

```
Person *firstPerson = [[Person alloc] initWithfirstName:@"Zen" lastName:@"Yong" email:@"" phoneNumber:@""];
person = firstPerson;

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:person, nil];

personArray = array;

[array release];
```

3) List the list of person's information in a table view

```
int row = [indexPath row];
Person *aPerson = (Person *)[self.personArray objectAtIndex:row];

cell.textLabel.text = aPerson.firstName;
```

Can you help to advise why I am getting the error listed at the beginning of the thread?

Appreciate your help on this!

Zhen

Comment: Where are you allocating and initializing personArray

Comment: @Krishnabhadra, I created a new Mutable Array and initialized it. "NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:person, nil];" I then assign it to my personArray "self.personArray = array;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're crashing due to a dangling pointer.  You set personArray array to be the array you created, but then you release the array, leaving personArray as a dangling pointer.  From what you posted I'm assuming personArray is a property on the class.  If so, changing:

```
personArray = array;
```

to

```
self.personArray = array;
```

should fix the problem.  The way you have it now the array pointer is just being assigned to the personArray pointer.  You have to call set setter method for the property to get the proper memory management.

Comment: yes that was the mistake I made. I changed it according to what you mentioned and now it works :) Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

This problem typicaly occurs when you have over released an object and the space has been reused for something else (a CALayer in your case).  I can't see the specific problem here that might be causing that, but you have a definite bug:

```
Person *firstPerson = [[Person alloc] initWithfirstName:@"Zen" lastName:@"Yong" email:@"" phoneNumber:@""];
person = firstPerson;

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:person, nil];

personArray = array;

[array release];
```

That creates an array and then immediately releases it.  It's likely that the array has been deallocated.  The person object in it, however, has not been released, so unless you do it later, it leaks.  You probably wanted something more like:

```
Person *firstPerson = [[Person alloc] initWithfirstName:@"Zen" lastName:@"Yong" email:@"" phoneNumber:@""];

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObject: firstPerson];

[firstPerson release];
```

You then have to save the array somewhere, so if personArray is an instance variable, you can just do

```
personArray = array; // personArray must be nil beforehand to stop leaks.
```

or if it is a property (this is better):

```
[self setPersonArray: array]; // or equivalently self.personArray = array;
[array release];
```

On a final unrelated note, it is considered better not to use properties in the `-init` or `-dealloc` methods.  Your `-init` should probably look like:

```
if(self = [super init]) 
{
    firstName = [thisFirstName copy];
    lastName = [thisLastName copy];
    email = [thisEmail copy];
    phoneNumber = [thisPhoneNumber copy];
}
```

And don't forget to release everything in `-dealloc`.

Comment: thanks for the response :) Yeap I realized that it was the way I was assigning the arrays. Terrible mistake. Thanks and my code is working now. Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: thanks again for the note:) Can I clarify with you why it is not good to use properties in the init methods? Also why is it also better to do a copy?

Comment: @Zhen: The main reason for not using the properties in `-init` is that any subclass could override the properties.  Similarly for `-dealloc` and additionally in `-dealloc` setting the property to nil would cause KVO to trigger wrongly.  I used `-copy` because your input parameters were all `NSString`s.  `NSString` supports `NSCopying`.  By the way, your `NSString` properties should be declared `copy` rather than `retain`.