# iOS app crashing when testing over test flight

Tags: ios, crash, testflight

I have an iOS app that I need to test on other devices over **testflight**.
When I run the app directly from XCode it works perfectly (both debug and release mode).
But when I archive the IPA file and download it over testflight it crashes when loading a `viewcontroller` with a `scrollview` with images;.

It never crashed in Xcode,only when installing from testflight.

Stack trace I got,

> : -[CALayer _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x1d570730 : *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CALayer
>   _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d570730'
>   *** First throw call stack:   (0x32a452a3 0x3a8e597f 0x32a48e07 0x32a47531 0x3299ef68 0x3486929f 0x34861eb3 0x7a3cf 0x3486c595
>   0x348c114b 0x348c1091 0x348c0f75 0x348c0e99 0x348c05d9 0x348c04c1
>   0x348aeb93 0x348ae833 0x7860f 0x3490f28d 0x34991f81 0x33353277
>   0x32a1a5df 0x32a1a291 0x32a18f01 0x3298bebd 0x3298bd49 0x365552eb
>   0x348a1301 0x30e1f 0x3ad1cb20)

What can cause such a problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713450/objective-c-terminating-app-due-to-uncaught-exception-nsinvalidargumentexcepti

Comment: Have you tried symbolicating the crash report to see the call stack leading up the the exception?

Comment: Did you try deleting the app then downloading from Testflight?

Comment: Yes i have tried reinstalling a few times

Comment: Sounds unrelated to testflight. I would bet on a bug that is always there but becomes visible by pure conincidence when using testflight.

Comment: also think it's unrelated to testflight but what i don't understand is why does it run perfectly through Xcode but not through test flight. First time i encounter something like this, any advice/ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The crash is 100% unrelated to the distribution method (here OTA distribution of an Ad-Hoc build via  Testflight).
2. You need to symbolicate that crash report using Xcode and will then see the file, method and line number in your app where it crashes. Drag the crash report into Xcode organizer crashes section and hope you still have all the files required for this to work. That is the .app and .dSYM bundles that where generated for this build and these being indexed via Spotlight.
3. The exception message is already pretty clear and says a lot about what is happening:

   `: -[CALayer _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d570730 : * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CALayer _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d570730' *`

   - The exception is a `NSInvalidArgumentException`
   - You code is calling a method/selector on an object that doesn't know this method/selector
   - This hints that you are having a memory issue (No, ARC is no magic and does **NOT** solve all your memory issues automatically)
   - Check your code for retain cycles (e.g. when using async completion blocks), memory leaks or zombies. Basically check for any memory related problem. There are multiple threads and documentation on StackOverflow or other places on what to do and how to check for these.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me sort out this issue :)